# Importing raw unstructured text file data into a Databricks table

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have a bunch of text files (all with a file extension of ".flib") stored in an Azure Blob Storage container. I would like to read these files into an Azure Databricks table with two columns in it: (1) the `SourceFileName` which would contain the name of each file (1 row in the table per FLIB file), and (2) the `File_Data` column which would be a string representation of the text in that file. I'm looking for what the code would need to look like in a Databricks Notebook (using SQL Mode) to accomplish this.

Why would I want to do this? Reasons. Reasons is why.

My best attempt:

```
storage_account_name = "<my_account_name>"
storage_account_key = "<redacted>"
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", storage_account_key)
container_name = "raw-flibs"

%sql
USE CATALOG "flib-dev";
USE beta;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flib_raw_data;
CREATE TABLE flib_raw_data 
USING delta
AS
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(value), '/', 1) AS SourceFileName,
  value AS File_Data
FROM EXPLODE("wasbs://raw-flibs@<my_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/raw_data/*.flib")
WHERE
  value LIKE '%.flib';
```

Produces exceptions, I'm happy to post them but I'm positive its because I'm not using correct syntax (I just don't know what the correct syntax is). **Any ideas where I'm going awry?**

Comment: Provide the sample content in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function **`read_files`** by specifying the format as `text`.

Below is the file I am having.

[image]

```sql
%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flib_raw_data;
CREATE TABLE flib_raw_data 
USING delta
AS
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(value), '/', 1) AS SourceFileName,
  value AS File_Data
FROM read_files("wasbs://<container_name>@<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/flibs/*flib",
    format => 'text')
```

Output:

[image]

Based on the content, you will get the file name and values.

Comment: Thanks (+1), but this is interesting: for me, the `File_Data` is correct, however `SourceFileName` is the same value as `File_Data`, but is just the string-reverse of it! Meaning if `File_Data` is: "some text in a file", then `SourceFileName` is "elif a ni txet emos", whereas I want `SourceFileName` to be the name of the file the `File_Data` came from. Ay ideas? Thanks again so much!

Comment: You can use `_metadata.file_name` column check this doc https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html#:~:text=You%20can%20get%20metadata%20information,reference%20it%20in%20your%20query.

Comment: Yep with `REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(_metadata.file_path), '/', 1)) as SouceFileName` this works great, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help on this the other day @JayashankarGS, for what it's worth I have a very similar (but slightly different) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668352/reading-text-files-into-databricks-table-with-multiline-enabled).