# Reading text files into Databricks table with multiLine enabled

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

**Please note:** I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77655662/importing-raw-unstructured-text-file-data-into-a-databricks-table) to this yesterday but now have a new (evolved) need and am asking this here as an iteration of a similar (but new) problem I am having with Databricks/Spark.

I have a bunch of text files (all with a ".flib" extension) living on an Azure Storage container. I am trying to read these files into an Azure Databricks table with two columns: (1) `FileName` which contains the name of the FLIP file being read off the container, and (2) `FileData` which contains all the text of each FLIB file.

My best attempt so far is:

```
%sql
USE CATALOG "data-beta";
USE data_beta_dev;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_beta;
CREATE TABLE data_beta 
USING delta
AS
SELECT
  REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(_metadata.file_path), '/', 1)) as SouceFileName,
  value AS File_Data
FROM read_files("wasbs://<redacted>@<redacted>.blob.core.windows.net/some/path/to/flibs/*.flib", format => 'text');

select * from data_beta;
```

While this works, it produces the undesirable result that each and every line of each and every FLIB file gets put into its own row in the `data_beta` table.

So if there is a file called `hello.flib` on that container, and that file contain 150 lines of text in it, then the code above will produce 150 rows in the `data_beta` table. Each row will have a `FileName` value of "hello.flib", but will have a `FileData` value of a different line of text from that FLIB file.

Instead, I want 1 row per file. So if `hello.flib` contains 150 lines, I'll still only get 1 row for that file, that has a huge clob of data inside of it's `FileData` value (all 150 lines of text).

Can anyone see how I can accomplish this?

Comment: maybe set the [lineSep option](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/read_files.html#text-options) to a character that is not in the files?

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately thats impossible to know ahead of time, the container will be autopopulated with client-provided files and there's no telling what crazy characters they may/may not contain over time.

Comment: What about the [wholeText option](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/read_files.html#text-options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `binaryFile` as format and decode it.

```py
%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flib_raw_data;
CREATE TABLE flib_raw_data 
USING delta
AS
SELECT
 REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(path), '/', 1)) as SouceFileName,
  decode(content,'utf-8') AS File_Data
FROM read_files("wasbs://data@jgsblob.blob.core.windows.net/flibs/*flib",
    format => 'binaryFile')
```

Here, path is column having file path, and content is the column having whole data.

Output:

| SouceFileName | File_Data |
| --- | --- |
| first.flib | random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcd random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcds random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcds random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcds random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcds random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcds random words/jayashankar/ayajksdjcnsdklcd |